# VSCode - custom snippet within gql tag/string within a TS file

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, graphql, vscode-snippets

I'm building out an API in Graphql using ApolloServer and Apollo Subgraphs. I'm writing in TS, but in order to use the subgraph feature, I need to wrap my schema with `gql`.
E.g.

```js
import { gql } from 'apollo-server-core';

export const typeDefs = gql`
    extend schema @link(url: "https://specs.apollo.dev/federation/v2.0", import: ["@key", "@shareable"])

    type User {
        id: Int!
        firstName: String
        lastName: String
        email: String!
    }
`;
```

Unfortunately when coming to try and add some custom snippets for the `graphql-constraint-directive` I can't get them to work within the backticks. Is there a way to do this?

Currently I have this snippet, which I tried adding into the typescript.json snippet file, but as I said, does not work within the backticks.

```json
"GraphQL Constraint Directive": {
    "prefix": ["@constraint", "constraint"],
    "body": ["@constraint(${1:format}: ${2:email}$0"]
}
```

Essentially when I'm defining an input types within the `` gql`SDL here`; ``, I want to be able to write the word "con" after each field and then be able to select the snippet from the autocomplete dropdown.

```
input loginInput {
    email: String! @constraint(format: email)
    password: String!  @constraint(minLength: 9, maxLength: 32)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To get your snippets to show up in backticks, try changing your `quickSuggestions` setting.  You need to set `strings` to `on` so that suggestions (which include snippets) will show up automatically.  By the way, you should be able to trigger the suggestions/snippets to show manually with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> even with the `strings` setting to `off`.

[image: changing quick suggestions setting]

Comment: Doesn't seem to be doing the trick :( still wont show the snippets.